# Display Youtube video in iframe

Tags: html, security, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Website **example1.com** has a Youtube video embedded. Website **example2.com** has an `iframe` that displays **example1.com**. Seems that due to Youtube policies, this video can be watched from **example1.com** but not from **example2.com** (inside an `iframe`). Is there a way to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried and its worked...

create a.html  and paste this code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/m7dSteMFhZI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

create b.html and add this code

```
<iframe width="600" height="350" src="a.php" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```